# im using splade SPA technology in laravel 10 facing issue in public folder js assets not loding

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, inertiajs, laravel-10

I'm new in laravel SPLADE I'm using themeforest admin theme for my project.

I'm using theme forest admin html template in SPLADE, I'm facing js script issue, when I'm using link tag to navigate to another page like home to profile page, js script not working I mean pagination, drop-down list, graphics charts, not working, if I make hard refresh that time it work but style sheets working when navigate to another page , without hard refresh, help me to fix this problem.

my code where I loaded all style sheet and js file linked.

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/dashlite.css?ver=3.1.3">
        <link id="skin-default" rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/theme.css?ver=3.1.3">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js' ])

        @spladeHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @splade
    </body>
    <script src="./assets/js/bundle.js?ver=3.1.3"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/scripts.js?ver=3.1.3"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/charts/gd-analytics.js?ver=3.1.3"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/libs/jqvmap.js?ver=3.1.3"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: $Ahmadz Issa  No